# execute PHP snippet saved on a textbox inside wp_options table

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a textbox where I save (inside `wp_options` table) this php snippet:

```
<?php if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ){ echo 'I\'m an admin!'; } ?>
```

and I like to execute that code in my html like this:

```
$geo_desktop = get_option( 'geo_desktop' );     

if ( !empty( $geo_desktop ) ) { echo '<div class="desktop">' . $geo_desktop . '</div>'; }
```

But this isn't outputting anything and I should see:

```
I'm an admin!
```

However, if I type only text inside that text box, it output's text like a charm...

How can I do this output my `PHP` code?

Comment: If your code is exactly; `echo 'I'm an admin!';} ` then that is not valid PHP... `echo 'I\'m an admin!';} `

Comment: @IsThisJavascript I forgot to escape it... Edited, thanks! Not working whoever...

Comment: I wouldn't know besides that as I don't work in wordpress. Thought I'd point out that little issue tho.

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this way :

```
$data = 'I\'m an admin!';
<?php if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ){ add_option('geo_desktop',$data); } ?>
```

then you can call wp_options

```
$geo_desktop = get_option( 'geo_desktop' );     

if ( !empty( $geo_desktop ) ) { echo '<div class="desktop">' . $geo_desktop . '</div>'; }
```